How to do a three color fill in R barchart?
I created a win/loss barchart with the y variable, wnls, coded -1 for loss and 1 for win.  Then the bars were filled with red/loss and win/green.  The code I used is below:
  plot1<-ggplot(data=puck3 %>% 
                mutate(win_loss = ifelse(wnls < 0, "loss", "win")), 
              aes(x=GP, y=wnls, fill = win_loss)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green")) +
  geom_col() +
  ylim(-5,5)

I now want to expand the data set to include draws as well with loss/draw/win coded -1/0/1.  Then the fill colors would be red/yellow/green.  How do I alter the code above to do a three-color fill?
Thanks for the help.

Change line 2 to mutate(win_loss = case_when(wnls == -1 ~ 'loss', wlns == 0 ~ 'draw', wnls == 1 ~ 'win')) and then just add another color to the scale fill.

Also, note that geom_bar(stat = "identity") was superseded by geom_col() over 8 years ago. There are presumably a lot of old tutorials out there which haven't been updated, since loads of folks still seem to be learning this syntax.

This seems to do the trick.  Thanks.
